# Broadcast receiver not receiving intent and haven't found a solution

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

1.This is the class that sends broadcast to main Activity:

```
public class LecturaDatos extends Service {
inetnt = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
sendBroadcast(inetnt);
}
```

2.This is main Activity and receives the broadcast:

```
class xReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1) {
Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
System.out.println("received");
}
}
```

3.Finally this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.haizea_android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="5"
android:targetSdkVersion="5" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver android:name="xReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.A_CUSTOM_INTENT">
</action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
android:name=".LecturaDatos"
android:enabled="true" />
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I don't know why but it doesn't work and I have seen similar problems and tried several solutions but they haven't worked for me

Comment: where are you sending the action as part of the intent?

Answer (score 0):

you should set action to your broadcasted intent e.g.

```
    inetnt.setAction("com.javacodegeeks.android.A_CUSTOM_INTENT");
```